# Visual Mode increasing numbers by 1

Tags: visual-block, line-numbers

I have many rows with numbers, some rows are blank though:

```
1         some text
2         some text
7         some text
         some text
9         some text
11         some text
         some text
17         some text
```

Is there a block edit way to increase each number by 1, but not touching the black ones? i.e. to result as

```
2         some text
3         some text
8         some text
         some text
10         some text
12         some text
         some text
18         some text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- Block select the numbers (<kbd>Ctrl v</kbd> and move the cursor to the bottom of the text)
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl a</kbd>

In your example `ggVG`<kbd>Ctrl a</kbd> will also make it.

Answer (score 0):

Only <kbd>Ctrl a</kbd> increment the first number of a line.

```
2 some text
3 some text 1
  some text 5
7 some text 7
8 some text
10 some text 9
```

Change also the number 5 in line 3. The result was

```
3 some text
4 some text 1
  some text 6
8 some text 7
9 some text
11 some text 9
```

Here it is necessary to mark only the numbers on the left side with <kbd>Ctrl v</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl a</kbd>

Another good way to increment numbers was <kbd>g</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl a</kbd>. That increment 1 for the first marked line, 2 for the second and so on.

```
0 some text 5
0 some text 5
0 some text 5
0 some text 5
```

<kbd>ggVG</kbd> <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl a</kbd> and then you have

```
1 some text 5
2 some text 5
3 some text 5
4 some text 5
```

This also increment the first number so that the 5 was unchanged.